# jasper reports subreports to main report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to make some changes in the reporting for the previously developed web application, I've got both `.jrxml` and `.jasper` files to edit 
for that I've used :

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
public class CompileReport {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
....  
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile("C:\\Users\\rohinkumar\\workspace\\  \\src\\resources\\\\old.jrxml","C:\\Users\\rohinkumar\\workspace\\\\WebContent\\old.jasper");
                } 
catch (JRException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and when I try to edit the main report in the ireport and build it I could see the error evaluating expression error in the logs.

I think the main report is unable to access the parameters passed from the subreports

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: You should post both JRXML.